# Conjugate then Derivative

Tags: complex

[image]

the function in front of e^imθ is a complex function of time “t”。that's to say ,if there is a complex function of t ,eg:f[t] =a[t] +i*b[t] （a[t]and b[t] is real function）
my problem is when I input a D[Conjugate[g[t]],it doesn't output Conjugate[D[g[t],t]],but output Conjugate'[g[t]]*g'[t],how can I reach my goal Without breaking this function into real numbers plus imaginary numbers？

[image]

Comment: I have many functions like f[t] to deal with

Comment: please provide your expression in mathematica code. [Here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951) are also pointers to copy and format code on this site.